# issue in locking a own object in synchronized block

Tags: java

I have a class and i make synchronized lock in that class for the same class object 
For ex.

```
class Demo{
    private Demo obj=new Demo();
    synchronized(obj){
         //some code here
    }
}
```

then it gives error of stack overflow but i write the same code as

```
class Demo{
    private static Demo obj=new Demo();
    synchronized(obj){
         //some code here
    }
}
```

Then it works fine so please any one is there to explain me logically what is happening here.

Comment: Is `Class` a typo of `class`?

Comment: @Sahil Take a look at the history, that's the way it came it - I just hit the formatting

Comment: oh sorry @MadProgrammer

Answer (score 9):

It's nothing to do with synchronization. You'll have the exact same problem with this code:

```
class Demo {
    private Demo obj=new Demo();
}
```

You're saying that in order to create an instance of `Demo`, you need to create a new instance of `Demo` - which will create another new instance of `Demo` etc. In your `static` version, there's only *one* static field, initialized *once*, so you don't get this infinite recursion.

If you want some code to synchronize on *itself*, you can just use `this`:

```
synchronized(this) {
    ...
}
```

Personally I would recommend synchronizing on a separate object which was never exposed though:

```
public class Demo {
    private final Object lock = new Object();
    ...
    // In a method
    synchronized(lock) {
        ...
    }
}
```

It's easier to reason about locks when you know that the only thing which knows about that reference is the `Demo` object itself.